# How to pass id from different table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Devise Gem to store user.
Created One to Many association between User to Project.
Created One to Many Association Between User and Site and Then One to Many Association between Project and Site.
But the error is i am not able to Assign project_id to Site from User Creation form. i am able to Assign from console. here is my code-

sites_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @site = current_user.sites.build(site_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @site.save
        format.html { redirect_to @site, notice: 'Transactions was successfully Uploaded.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @site }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def site_params
      params.require(:site).permit(:name, :amount)
    end
```

site.rb(model)

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
```

User.rb

```
  has_many :projects
  has_many :sites
```

project.rb

```
  has_many :sites, dependent: :destroy
```

How can i pass `project_id` on site creation. Is there any other simple way to resolve such problem?

Comment: Please add the method `site_params`'s code to the question.

Comment: @anurag just added.

Comment: Also, can you add the context of `project_sites` from your code. Like is that a model too?

Comment: @anurag it;s mistaken it's context of  ```sites ```

Comment: is `project_id` passed in params?

Comment: @anurag no, not from form. i want to pass ```project_id``` during creation of ```site```. like i pass ```user_id```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments in the question:

```
# project_id needs to be available to the method, 
# in order to be added to site.
#
# Either pass it through params or get it from database 
# based on your business logic.

site_params = site_params.merge({project_id: project_id})
@site = current_user.sites.build(site_params)
```

Should help.

Comment: still not able to assign same ```project_id`` ` of user project and site

Comment: please add the code, where you are setting the value for `project_id`. or how are you getting project_id inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try permitting the foreign key as well.

```
    def site_params
      params.require(:site).permit(:name, :amount, :project_id)
    end
```